# Different usage of grep

Tags: grep

I know grep can be use to do partial search, for example if i use

```
echo "Enter example"
read example

echo "Enter Subject"
read subject
grep -i ^$example info.txt | grep -i ^[^,]*:$subject
```

The output will be all the lines of string that has, let's say i key in "example", it will display all the lines of string that has the string "example".

I need this function so that the user can do a general search on what are the list of available reading materials there are in the info.txt.

I am currently using if statements, if both $example and $subject have information in it, it will do specific search, like literally string matching string, else it will return false.

Is there anyway to make the search more flexible, or to let it search specifically, like there are many examples in the info.txt.

1. Example 1:Basic mathematics
2. Example 2:Advance mathematics
3. Example 3:How to create a good example ?

So if i key in "example" and "mathematics", it will return false. However, if i key in "example 1" and "basic mathematics", it will echo out the output. I asked around, most of my friends recommended me to use awk, but if i do that , i will have to redo my whole script as I'm using grep in most function to do searches.

My teacher only taught us grep at that point of time, therefore, only understand basic grep and did not know about awk.

Comment: You could also use `sed`. But I think it should work anyway, you just have to be careful not to restrict your regular expression too much. grep doesn't do exact matching unless you force it to (for instance, by searching '^example:' instead of just 'example[^:]*:'. And be careful, you should quote "$example" and "$subject" otherwise spaces will result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Try `grep -i "^$example.*:.*$subject" info.txt`

Comment: Sorry, typo, re-edited

Comment: Are you philosophically opposed to shell quotes or something? You keep asking these questions and practically every answer you get says ... "You should quote that..."

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about @mikeserv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice little page on shellhacks.com that shows examples "[Using BASH "Grep OR / Grep AND / Grep NOT" Operators](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Using-BASH-Grep-OR-Grep-AND-Grep-NOT-Operators)", **and** it has the `sed` & `awk` equivalents. I'll paste it here, you could use them to search for `$subject` and/or/not `$example`, in a certain or any order.

## [Using BASH "Grep OR / Grep AND / Grep NOT" Operators](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Using-BASH-Grep-OR-Grep-AND-Grep-NOT-Operators)

In the following article you'll find several examples, that show how to use OR / AND / NOT operators with Linux GREP / SED / AWK commands.

It is quite a common task to use such [Linux command line tools](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Categories/Linux-Commands) as grep, sed and awk for [parsing files with regular expressions](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Categories/Linux-BASH-Scripting/Parsing).

I'll show how to **find all lines**, that **contain any of the several patterns**, how to print all lines in a file, that **match multiple patterns** and how to find and print all lines, that **do not match a pattern**.

### Grep 'OR' Operator

Find all the lines in a file, that match any of the following patterns.

Using GREP command :

```
grep "pattern1\|pattern2" file.txt
grep -E "pattern1|pattern2" file.txt
grep -e pattern1 -e pattern2 file.txt
egrep "pattern1|pattern2" file.txt
```

Using AWK command :

```
awk '/pattern1|pattern2/' file.txt
```

Using SED command :

```
sed -e '/pattern1/b' -e '/pattern2/b' -e d file.txt
```

### Grep 'AND' Operator

Find and print all the lines in a file, that match multiple patterns.

Using GREP command :

```
grep -E 'pattern1.*pattern2' file.txt # in that order
grep -E 'pattern1.*pattern2|pattern2.*pattern1' file.txt # in any order
grep 'pattern1' file.txt | grep 'pattern2' # in any order
```

Using AWK command :

```
awk '/pattern1.*pattern2/' file.txt # in that order
awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/' file.txt # in any order
```

Using SED command :

```
sed '/pattern1.*pattern2/!d' file.txt # in that order
sed '/pattern1/!d; /pattern2/!d' file.txt # in any order
```

### Grep 'NOT' Operator

Find and print all the lines, that do not match a pattern.

Using GREP command :

```
grep -v 'pattern1' file.txt
```

Using AWK command :

```
awk '!/pattern1/' file.txt
```

Using SED command :

```
sed -n '/pattern1/!p' file.txt
```

---

Here's a link to [GNU's Grep manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/index.html#dir). It has lots of good info, including on [Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions) and some [Usage examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Usage.html#Usage).

This page is a ["cheat sheet" on RegEx](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/).

Comment: just another question, i need 1 of the function to find and print the exact pattern

like the pattern 1 and pattern 2, have the be exactly what it is in the file.txt before it will display the output

Comment: It sounds like your "pattern1" will have to be entered exactly then. If there are any common characters before/after a "subject" or "example" entry, you could use those in your pattern... like if a subject always begins with a "`: `" you could put "`: $subject`" to avoid matching the wrong part of a different line. I'll add a link to a GNU grep manual at the end

Comment: there is a criteria whereby if the user input partial search in pattern1 and pattern2, it will give a false. How can i do that in grep, i googled and ask around, most examples are either awk or using array.

Comment: `grep` is spec'd for ERE which is better equipped to handle OR/NOT cases - and will do so even within subexpressions.

Comment: that's why i asked, is it possible to get the output i need via the given conditions and searched information, if not, i will probably have to redo my script @mikeserv

Comment: @mikeserv From what I can tell, for GNU grep at least, basic & extended RegExes are functionally equivalent... In the Debian/Ubuntu/Mint grep I've currently got (grep (GNU grep) 2.16) the man page (& gnu link in answer) says *"there is no difference in available functionality between the basic and extended syntaxes"* and *"In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ‘?’, ‘+’, ‘{’, ‘|’, ‘(’, and ‘)’ lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions ‘\?’, ‘\+’, ‘\{’, ‘\|’, ‘\(’, and ‘\)’."* and some `{` differences... different looks but similar effects?

Comment: Yes, w/ GNU `grep` that's basically true via its extensions to BRE - but those same extensions are likely to gen syntax errors and/or render unintended results in a portable script - and are also more difficult to read especially in that they mean one thing in a portable context and basically the opposite thing in a GNU context. By spec i meant POSIX. Still, it is a very good answer. Sorry that i forgot to upvote at first.

Comment: Thanks, I get the feeling that portability and grep aren't very good friends ;-)